# Dynamic Data Masking in SSAS cube process

Tags: sql-server, ssas, data-masking, dynamic-data-masking

I have dynamic masked data in my SQL Server DB and I want to know what will happen to that if I used this data in  my cube processing . would it be still a masked data is the cube , and can I use the roll security for that or not?

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on the credential that is being used to connect to the database via cube.
In case if the account has admin access or non masking, then original data would be available else masked data would be in cube